# This regex is inefficient. Why does it crash Sublime Text 2's stack?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Answered:

This regex works:

```
<item>(?:(?!</item>).|\n)*?(?:(?=201[0-3]</pubDate>))(?:(?!</item>).|\n)*?</item>
```

while this one crashes the stack:

```
<item>(?:(?!</item>).|\n)*(?:(?=201[0-3]</pubDate>))(?:(?!</item>).|\n)*</item>
```

This also works, without lookaheads:

```
(?s)<item>.*?201[0-3]</pubDate>.*?</item>
```

Original question:

I have an XML file in Sublime Text 2 (example below). I want to find all the `<item`> elements that contain a `<pubDate`> element from the years 2010 through 2013.

The above regex works correctly, but when I do find all (the file is about 1MB with about 120 matches) ST2 runs out of stack space.

What horrible inefficiencies lurk above?

Example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <channel>
        <item>
            <title>This will match</title>
            <link>http://gcanyon.posterous.com/</link>
            <pubDate>Sat Mar 10 10:22:00 -0800 2012</pubDate>
            <dc:creator><![CDATA[Geoff Canyon]]></dc:creator>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>This won't</title>
            <link>http://gcanyon.posterous.com/</link>
            <pubDate>Tue Jun 30 05:01:32 -0700 2009</pubDate>
            <dc:creator><![CDATA[Geoff Canyon]]></dc:creator>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: This is typically not what regexps should be used for :)

Comment: [Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) due to greedyness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greedy greedy regex. For example:

```
(?:(?!</item>).|\n)*
```

will go all the way to the next `</item>` while it's not what you want, you only don't want it to go farther I'll assume.

You should find happiness in [lazy operators](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

PS: Sorry I don't have enough time to look more deeply into your regex. Hopefully it'll solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction. Adding ? after the two *s allows the regex to find all without crashing the stack. I'm not sure how greedy vs. lazy applies to lookaheads in this context, so I have more learning to do. But the problem is solved it seems: `<item>(?:(?!</item>).|\n)*?(?:(?=201[0-3]</pubDate>))(?:(?!</item>).|\n)*?</item>`

Comment: @GeoffCanyon - The problem was probably catastrohic backtracking, which I'll explain in an answer. The pattern could still use some improvement; I'll explain that too.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two problems. One is your whole approach (so **skip to the bottom if you just want my real advice**), but it looks like the other is [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

### Why this is breaking

If we simplify your pattern a bit, it boils down to this:

```
{a}{x*}{x*}{b}
```

Notice the two `x*`'s right next to each other? Yes, there's a `(?=y)` between them, but let's ignore that for a minute, because I don't think the engine is using that efficiently to limit the amount of work it's doing. Suppose you have a string like `axxxxxxxb` and you want to match it against the pattern. Since there are two `x*` tokens next to each other, the engine can't tell easily where one group ends and the other begins. So it tries to put them all in the first `{x*}` bucket, since the `*` is greedy:

```
{a}{xxxxxxx}{}{b}
```

Great, right? It matched, so we can move on. But consider something like `axxxxxxQxb`. That doesn't match on the first pass, so the engine has to keep trying permutations:

```
{a}{xxxxxxx}{}{Q} #nope
{a}{xxxxxx}{x}{Q} #nope
{a}{xxxxx}{xx}{Q} #nope
...
```

Eventually, this takes so long it blows up your stack.

### Improving the regex

So how to fix it? Well, there's this:

```
(?:(?=201[0-3]</pubDate>))
```

I think the engine will do a better job if it's an affirmative token, rather than a lookahead. It doesn't need to be a lookahead anyway; you can just use this (with or without the `\s*`):

```
201[0-3]\s*</pubDate>
```

The `(?:(?!</item>).)*` after that is redundant; you should just need a lazy `.*?`.

Also, you can use the Multiline option to make `.` also match newlines, but I'm not sure whether that will make any difference in terms of speed/execution. It'll be shorter to write, though.

The whole thing would look something like:

```
<item>(?:(?!</item>).)*?201[0-3]</pubDate>.*?</item>  #plus the /m flag
```

### The REAL solution

But I think the real problem is that you're [using regex at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/399649). This looks like XML. Why aren't you using an XML parser? If you're using .NET, LINQ to XML is perfect for the exact job you're describing, including the part about specific values in the nested `pubdate`. Should be way easier and more efficient than a regex.

Comment: Sublime Text has a very nice "find all of this and then copy it" function. I'm not using .NET, and I almost never use XML. I think I was over thinking the regex. I've updated the question with `(?s)<item>.*?201[0-3]</pubDate>.*?</item>` which also works.